# LiveCycle : Looping through dynamic checkboxes

Tags: javascript, livecycle-designer

I am new to LiveCycle and javascript. I am working on a form which dynamically populates values from a web service call. I have to use these valus to filter out some pre populated values. The dynamically populated values has check boxes to it. I need to go through this dynamically populated values and return corresponding clciked value of the checkbox. I tried many things to access the value of the dynamic checkbox like

```
Root.subformpath.resolveNode.("checkboxname["+ i +"]").rawValue
```

to try to loop through values. But it always returns null value. this.checkboxname.rawValue on click event returns the dynamic name. But I need to loop through all checkbox every time a click event happens

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JS, you can use resolveNodes to make a list, then a for loop to cycle through.

```
var checkBoxList = xfa.resolveNodes("checkBoxName[*]");

for (var i = 0; i<checkBoxList.length; i++){
  if (checkBoxList.item(i).rawValue == 1){
    //do something for checked boxes
  }
  else{
    //do something else for unchecked boxes
  }
}
```